# What is the best way to visualize large data sets in QT

Tags: user-interface, qt, plot

I am working on a Qt project, which require visualization of very large data sets (time + value measurements). By very large I mean millions of values.

I need to support scrolling across these values and zoom-in/out operations in the time axis. The ultimate zoom-out should show all the data set sub-sampled to match the window width.

Here are the Qt toolkits I know for drawing the functions:

1. [QWT](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/)
2. [HippoDraw](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/grp/ek/hippodraw/)
3. [KD Chart](http://www.ics.com/products/qt/kdchart/)

I've actually two questions:

1. Do you know any other toolkit for drawing function using Qt?
2. What of the above tools will fit for my purposes better?

If you have any other relative comment / idea regarding my problem, feel free to share.

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you really want to use a plot? I'd try finding if there are better ways to present that many values. In any case, if you'll really do so, merge values together as you zoom out (maybe this is what you meant by sub-sampling)

Comment: Yes, I meant to merge the values. What are the other ways you are talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MathGL](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/) was designed to handle huge data set (about hundreds Mb or several Gb). It also have Qt widget.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm working in a QT Project too, and I'm using Qwt. I can say that Qwt is a good solution because is:

- Easy to use.
- Easy to learn.
- A complete source of good looking charts.

This is a starter tutorial about Qwt, I hope it helps: [Tutorial](http://www.digitalfanatics.org/projects/qt_tutorial/chapter11.html)

About the other options I cannot say anything because I don't know them.

See you!

Answer (score 0):

though Qwt is good; you might also want to give a try to the chart component from the [AnalogWidgets](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/AnalogWidgets?content=87780) set

[image: AnalogWidgets chart]